# Python coding needs fixing in lines 1

Tags: python

I need to return double the number of int a

```
public static int findDouble(int[] a, int b) {
    for(int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
```

Comment: 1. "product" means multiplication (i.e. x times y = x*y), you only use subtraction and addition in your code. 2. What do you intend to do with `n -= 2`?

Comment: Can you share some input/output you expect ? I don't any `*` time operator, nor something about the digits of N

Answer (score 2):

You may use

- `*` as the product operator
- `n%10` to get the last digit , `1234 % 10 => 4`
- `n/10` to get the remaining digits `1234 / 10 => 123`

```
public static int timesDigits(int n) {
    if (n <= 0) {
        return 1;
    }
    return (n % 10) * timesDigits(n / 10);
}
```

Tests

```
System.out.println(timesDigits(1234)); // 24 == 1*2*3*4
System.out.println(timesDigits(987654321)); // 362880 == 9*8*7*6*5*4*3*2*1
```